# Automated Ubuntu Desktop Build - DNS Failure on boot

Tags: ubuntu, ansible, vagrant, packer

I am trying to create an automated build of an Ubuntu Desktop 22.04.2 using the official guide (https://github.com/canonical/autoinstall-desktop) and then use ansible to configure it.  The automated build works as expected, but the ansible configuration fails.  After looking at the desktop, it has no DNS servers listed in etc/resolv.conf.  Enabling and disabling/enabling the NIC from the cli or the GUI fixes the issue (router is now listed), but after a reboot the same issue is present again.

Disabling and reenabling the NIC, doing a apt update and apt upgrade, and then rebooting solves it across reboots.  I am doing an apt update and apt upgrade in the automated build process as well as apt-get dist-upgrade, but there is a Software Update called "Ubuntu Base" that seems to only show up as a needed update after a user logs into the GUI for the first time.  Once that update is applied and the desktop rebooted, the issue is resolved.  I can then run the ansible playbook.

I have tried several methods to do an ipconfig eth0 down/up as the first step in the ansible playbook, but none of the methods seems to successfully work.  Guessing the down works, but the desktop never receives the up when the network goes down.  Not quite sure what else to try at this point.  Hoping someone else has come across this.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I setup an apt-cacher-ng instance and configured the build to point to it via IP address.  Updated my ansible playbook to do an apt upgrade and reboot before continuing with the rest of the playbook.  Followed this guide to setup apt-cacher-ng.

https://www.xmodulo.com/apt-caching-server-ubuntu-debian.html